# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter-4, intl, mbstring

I am setting the environment for the use of CodeIgniter4.
I want to use "extension=intl" or "extension=mbstring" in php.ini

php.ini

```php
extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
```

After that, when the local server is executed, the following error is output.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/intl' (no such file), '/usr/lib/intl' (no such file)), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl.so, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/intl.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/intl.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Feb  2 16:50:09 2022] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mbstring (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mbstring, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mbstring' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/mbstring' (no such file), '/usr/lib/mbstring' (no such file)), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mbstring.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mbstring.so, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mbstring.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/mbstring.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/mbstring.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
```

My extesion_dir's value is "/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902"

Diretory Tree in 20190902

```
.
└── xdebug.so
```

If so, I think it is an error that occurred because extension does not exist, but it is loaded when checked through actual phpinfo().

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfRXH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lheKk.png)

And run `php -m | grep "intl"`, it is exist

Comment: Have you tried restarting your php service via `brew services` etc?

Comment: Also do you see that error on the CLI, through your browser such as through Apache, or through both?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue myself with homebrew and php on my m1 macbook.

It was compiled into the PHP binary that is installed by homebrew, which means it's loaded without mentioning it in the ini file. This means you can't load it manually, and attempting to do so will cause a startup error that will show as a warning when running PHP from the command-line interface.

The best thing to do is just remove the line in the ini to load that module, since attempting to load it will fail.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes it seems so..... The extensions are already bundled and compiled with homebrew php installation and as you said its needless to uncomment in the php initialization file. I can find all these extensions when I run phpinfo() in browser. Thanks a lot, as a newbie to MAC and homebrew, it has helped me !

Answer (score 0):

phpinfo and php -m are different. running php in CLI can load a different ini file from the ini file loaded by your webserver configuration. Try running your phpinfo script using the built-in webserver (php -S localhost:88 phpinfo.php). Then access localhost:88 in the webbrowser.

Comment: I modified the ini file on the path that came out by running "php --ini".

Comment: And "php -S localhost:88 phpinfo.php"'s result is same phpinfo();. Intl and mbstring are still loaded and print same error